# ChromeCast Parse Segmented TTML

Tags: google-cast, chromecast, ttml

Hy!

I have an ism file with Smooth Streaming and PlayReady.
This ism contains the caption in segmented ttml format.

But this ttml has a new line character for example: p8:br
How can I parse it and replace theese characters to /n (or whatever that Google ChromeCast can handle)?

So than I can see the subtitle in 2 lines instead of one.

I know I can get the streaminfo with protocol.getStreamInfo(index), but what can I do after it?

**UPDATE #1**

We do an application for other platforms and the method there was the following. The ttml variable contains the caption of the movie.

```
  ttml = ttml.Replace("<p7:br />", "\n");
  ttml = ttml.Replace("<p8:br />", "\n");
  ttml = ttml.Replace("<p7:br/>", "\n");
  ttml = ttml.Replace("<p8:br/>", "\n");
  ttml = ttml.Replace("<br />", "\n");
  ttml = ttml.Replace("<br/>", "\n");
```

After the new line characters replaced to "\n", the application started to show the current text depends on the time (there was eg. a label at the bottom of the movie.)

**UPDATE #2**

Here is a sample from the dfxp:

```
   <p p7:region="speaker" p7:begin="00:04:31:21" p7:end="00:04:37:22"  xmlns:p7="http://www.w3.org/2006/10/ttaf1">Talán mert nem vagy olyan okos?<p7:br />Mert lassú a felfogásod?</p>
   <p p7:region="speaker" p7:begin="00:04:38:23" p7:end="00:04:42:11" xmlns:p7="http://www.w3.org/2006/10/ttaf1">Eressz, különben<p7:br />nem állok jót magamért.</p>  
   <p p7:region="speaker" p7:begin="00:04:52:17" p7:end="00:04:55:10" xmlns:p7="http://www.w3.org/2006/10/ttaf1">Mesélj a nagypapáról.</p>
   <p p7:region="speaker" p7:begin="00:05:08:18" p7:end="00:05:14:12"   xmlns:p7="http://www.w3.org/2006/10/ttaf1">A cukornádföldön voltam.<p7:br />Akkor kapott el, mikor egyedül voltam.</p>
```

At the last line ot the sample, the device couldn't recognized the  characters and show the subtitle the following way:

A cukornádföldön voltam.Akkor kapott el, mikor egyedül voltam.

Instead of

A cukornádföldön voltam.

Akkor kapott el, mikor egyedül voltam.

So I would like to do some similar operations with the help of ChromeCast API. But that would be easier to just simply change the characters, because the ChromeCast can handle the timing perfectly.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug that will be fixed in the Media Player library soon; that should address this namespace issue. I will update this post when a fix is released.

Comment: Thank you Les Vogel and Ali Naddaf! I'm looking forward to hearing this fix!

Comment: The fix is now available; please check the Release notes on our developer site to see the new url for the library.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with Engineering on this, and the [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) is converting br to newlines, we ignore the namespace.

If you have some samples that have problems, please send it to us.

Comment: I see. But my problem is that my segmented ttml caption is inside the manifest file and the new line character is "p8:br". 
You said that Media Player library converting "br" to newlines, but first of all I have to convert "p8:br" to "br" which needed for Media Player Library.

Comment: Is it enclosed?  <p8:br />  or just p8:br ??  I was told we weren't looking at the p8: namespace. (of course there could be a bug)

Comment: I updated with my question. Is there any way to look more namespaces? In that case we dont't have to write a parser to show caption.

Comment: We really need an example that gives us the whole vtt segment.  l e s v (at) g...

Comment: I've been asked what p7 & p8 namespaces are?  We can't find them.

Comment: I updated with my question and provided a sample caption from the dfxp.